# Insertar dos datos recogiendo una id mediante PHP

Tags: php

Buenas tengo una duda de como realizar lo siguiente:

Resulta que quiero ingresar varios datos en una base de datos de MySQL mediante PHP, estos datos tienen que ir a dos tablas de la cuales están relacionadas user_data con users_login mediante usuario_id, esto quiere decir que inserta los datos en la tabla user_data y luego con el id de user_data insertas usuario_id en users_logins con usuario, contraseña y usuario_id, pongo el código que he hecho y si podéis ayudarme sería un gran alivio:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {

    require_once 'db.php';

    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    // Recojer los valores del formulario de registro
    $nombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['nombre']) : false;

    $apellidos =  isset($_POST['apellidos']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['apellidos']) : false;

    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ?  mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['email'])) : false;


    $user =  isset($_POST['user']) ?  $_POST['user'] : false;

    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ?  mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['password'])) : false;


        // Cifrar la contraseña
        $password_secure = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 4]);

        // Insertar usuario en la tabla de user_data de la BBDD

        $sql = "INSERT INTO user_data VALUES(null, '$nombre', '$apellidos', '$email');";

        $save = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

      

        if ($save) {
            
            $usuario_id = $db->insert_id;

            $sql_login = "INSERT INTO users_login VALUES(null, $usuario_id ,'$user', '$password_secure');";

            mysqli_query($db, $sql_login);


            $_SESSION['completado'] = "El registro se ha completado con éxito";
            header('Location: ../login.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['errores']['general'] = "Fallo al guardar el usuario";
            header('Location: ../registro.php');
        }
}
header('Location: ../registro.php');
```

Sé que lo que he puesto de $usuario_id = $db->insert_id; está mal, pero no sé como hacerlo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Debes saber que le estás tirando a PHP un problema que debería ser resuelto a nivel de base de datos, precisamente para eso existen los TRIGGER o disparadores, que se activan por ejemplo cuando se inserta un registro en una tabla, para permitirte insertar un registro en otra tabla. Eso ocurre de forma automática y transparente para el usuario, sólo tienes que programar el TRIGGER y punto. Si se lo tiras a PHP, aparte de perder el tiempo reinventando la rueda, te expones a errores e inconsistencias y creas un entorno más lento. Te aconsejo que leas sobre TRIGGER.

Comment: ¿Por qué piensas  que el `$db->insert_id` está mal? ¿Qué error obtienes?

Comment: @DavidJP El valor se pone en cero, por eso creo que está mal.

Comment: Pero eso puede ser porque tengas algún fallo en el `INSERT` inicial, haz un `echo $db->error;` antes del `if($save)` y te aseguras de que se haya hecho esa inserción. Ya me dices...

Comment: @DavidJP Ya vi el error que tenía, y resulta que tenía un error en el `INSERT` y lo del $usuario_id = $db->insert_id estaba bien, arreglé el `INSERT` y ya se me inserta bien! Gracias!